# How to redirect users after password change in Django 2?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, backend

I have a password change view in my project. Instead of the default Django `password_change_done/done/` I want users to be redirected to my custom page eg homepage. For login we need to edit the settings and add `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. Is there anything like `PASSWORD_CHANGE_REDIRECT_URL` that we can specify in our settings.py file?

This is my URL patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mainapp.urls')),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name="login"),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name="logout"),
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'), name="password_reset"),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'), name="password_reset_done"),
    path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path('password_reset_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'), name="password_reset_complete"),
    path('change_password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='users/change_password.html'), name="password_change"),
    path('password_change_done/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_change_done.html'), name="password_change_done"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I want the users to be redirected to custom view and not the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify redirect url in [PasswordChangeView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView).

```py
path(
    'change_password/',
    auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
        template_name='users/change_password.html',
        success_url="<YOUR URL HERE>"
    ),
    name="password_change"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the success_url argument.
For example:

```
auth_views.YourView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('your-success_url'), name='....')
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) for more info

Comment: Why reverse_lazy?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar please check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy